# passing values from child window to parent window

Tags: javascript

Hi this is my first question in this site.

My problem is-I have created a jsp where in i have given one link to call another jsp (already created by some one) in a popup window.On saving some details in child window i want those values to be accessed in my parent window.But i dont have the permission to change the code of child window jsp. 
can anyone help me...?
Thanks,
the code i am using to open a popup is as follows.

```
function popUp(url){
    alert("inside popup");
    window.open(url,'newWindow','width=750,height=400,left=150,top=100,toolbar=no,resizable=true');
}
```

Comment: Thank you... problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Provided the `url` does not violate the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), you can access the window properties via the return value of `window.open()`, eg

```
var windowRef = window.open(url, ...);

var someElement = windowRef.document.getElementById("element-id");

var someJavaScriptVar = windowRef.someVar;
```